# Geht "beobachten, wie jemand etwas tut" auch ohne "wie"?

Tags: usage, style

Im Englischen kann man schön schreiben:

> I watch my son eating soup.

Im Deutschen muss man dagegen einen holprigen Nebensatz bilden:

> Ich beobachte, wie mein Sohn Suppe isst.
>   Ich beobachte meinen Sohn dabei, wie er Suppe isst.

Oder geht das auch schöner? Kann man etwa schreiben:

> Ich beobachte meinen Sohn Suppe essen.

Nein, oder? Aber wie geht es ohne dieses "wie", das mir so aufstößt?

Comment: @Em1 (first comment) Bei weitem nicht so holprig wie das theoretisch auch mögliche: "Ich beobachte meinen Suppe essenden Sohn."

Comment: @BMWurm But your sentence is unambiguous.

Comment: @Em1 True, although it was meant as a response to your first comment, your second appeared while I committed mine, clarified that with an edit .... although "Suppe essend beobachte ich meinen (ebenfalls) Suppe essenden Sohn" still works, sounds even more cumbersome though. Another thing: I would have said - in the original question: "I watch my son eating soup." as he's most likely doing it while I am talking about him doing it....

Comment: @BMWurm Yeah. Good catch. – I converted my comment to an answer. I think you should do likewise. Although more cumbersome, it **is** valid. EDIT: Never mind. Peasant combined both into one answer.

Answer (score 6):

Ich sehe auf Anhieb drei Lösungen:

Partizip I:

> Ich beobachte meinen Suppe essenden Sohn.

Substantivierung (Version 1):

> Ich beobachte meinen Sohn beim Suppeessen.

Substantivierung (Version 2):

> Ich beobachte meinen Sohn beim Essen der Suppe.

Ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob bei der Version 1 "*Essen*" ebenso gross geschrieben wird <strike>(ziemlich sicher aber schon)</strike>. <sup>Siehe dazu Amtl. Regelung [§37.2](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Amtlich/GetrZusammen/pgf37-38.html#pgf37-2), auf [canoonet](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Regeln/Getrennt-zusammen/Nomen.html#Anchor-11481), mit weiteren Beispielen im [canoonet Blog](https://blog.canoonet.eu/2013/12/05/wie-man-substantiviert-drachen-steigen-laesst/) oder im Duden die letzte Anmerkung in [Regel 54](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/getrennt-und-zusammenschreibung#K54).</sup> Ebenso könnten die substantivierten Versionen pedantisch betrachtet auch missverstanden werden, im Sinne, dass man selbst die Suppe isst und währenddessen den Sohn betrachtet.

Comment: Die Groß-/Kleinschreibung ist korrekt.

Comment: Danke, aber die Substanti4ungen sind ja noch unsäglicher als die wie-Konstruktion :-) Die Frage war ja nicht nur: Was geht stattdessen? Sondern betonte ja gerade die stilistische Schwäche und suchte also – womöglich allzu implizit – eine stilistisch bessere Formulierung. Die Partizip-Lösung ist aber schön. Danke dafür: +1.

Comment: @what Ich rate dir sehr die Substantivierungen zu verwenden. Es ist die gebräuchlichere und einfachere Variante.

Comment: @Em Aber nur in der gesprochenen Sprache. Schriftlich ist es plump.

Comment: Je nach Kontext ist das gar nicht pedantisch.

Comment: a translation that sounds a little archaic: *I see my son be eating soup*?

Answer (score 1):

Nach der Lektüre der bisherigen Antworten und Kommentare, fällt mir folgende Alternative ein:

> Ich beobachte meinen Sohn, während er Suppe isst.

Exakt dieselbe Konstruktion, wie die mit "wie", aber klingt für mich deutlich eleganter.

Comment: Exact corsespondence to the continuous form of the original in my opinion.

Comment: @guidot Mir scheint aber, dass ich bei "watch eating" den Vorgang des Essens beobachte, bei "beobachte meinen Sohn während" beobachte ich dagegen meinen Sohn (und ignoriere möglicherweise, dass er währenddessen isst). Diesen Fokus der Aufmerksamkeit übersetzt das "wie" genauer.

Comment: Das ändert aber leicht den Sinn des Satzes, da nun nicht mehr zwingend das Essen das Ziel der Beobachtung ist, sondern der Sohn.

Answer (score 1):

Das geht im Deutschen auch:

> Ich sehe meinen Sohn Suppe essen.

Die Bedeutung ist aber eine engere, nämlich nur die grundlegende Feststellung, dass er gerade beim Löffeln ist. Gezielte Aufmerksamkeit, ob er das Gesicht dabei verzieht,  kleckert, sauber aufisst, und so weiter wären dadurch nicht abgedeckt.

Answer (score 0):

Eine Konjunktion oder eine Präposition ist an der Stelle hilfreich und in diesem Fall standardsprachlich notwendig.

Man würde zwar sagen:

> 1. Ich sehe meinen Sohn Suppe essen.

Dabei sind direktes und indirektes Objekt an der Beugung erkennbar.

Der Satz würde mit "beobachten" aber holprig klingen. Das direkte Objekt wäre weiterhin richtig im Akkusativ:

> Ich beobachte meinen Sohn.

Daran kann entweder ein Relativsatz anschließen, bspw ".., weil er Suppe isst", oder eine adverbiale Phrase

> 2. Ich beobachte meinen Sohn beim Suppe essen

Zuerst fällt auf, dass "be-ob-achten" gleich zwei präverbale Präpositionen enthält. *be-* und *bei* haben die gleiche Wurzel. Das hat nicht besonders viel zu heißen, insoweit *bei* auch anderweitig verwendet wird, etwa "Ich achte meinen Sohn beim Suppe essen", "Ich helfe Ihm bei Hausaufgaben" (vgl aber "Beihilfe", "Behelf", "Beachtung", etc).

Die Präposition gehört immerhin zum Verb, wird in der Regel nicht ausgelassen, und hilft zumindest, den grammatischen Fall erkennen zu lassen. Dagegen wäre "wie" hochsprachlich falsch; vielleicht weil in der Regel ein qualitativer Vergleich auf "wie" folgt; "wie er Suppe isst" wirkt aber eher temporal, vgl oben andere Antwort ganz richtig "während", während "wenn" widerum meist kausal, nicht temporal verstanden wird; En "how he eats soup" wäre eben auch ambivalent, vorrangig auf Art und Weise bezogen; "while" vergleicht sich wiederum gut zum kausalen "weil". Um Nebensätze geht es in der Frage aber nicht.

Ich sprach eingangs von Notwendigkeit. So ist nicht ganz klar, wer gerade beim Suppe essen ist, der Sprecher oder der Sohn? Der Relativsatz mit "während er" ist daher die genaueste Aussage. Zwar wäre die Zweideutigkeit oft nicht verfänglich, wenn der Kontext ausreichend Präzedenz erahnen lässt. In parallelen Konstruktionen ist das aber nicht immer der Fall. Darauf wollte ich eigentlich hinaus, z.B. "I watch my dog eating cats". Das ist zweideutig. Natürlich ist das ein Ausnahmefall, wenn nicht gar falsch.

*bei* wird vielfältig eingesetzt. Dabei sind adverbiale Ortsbestimmungen von Tätigkeitsbeschreibungen abzugrenzen, also etwa "bei der Messe", "beim Schiff". Tatsächlich werden diese eher anders ausgedrückt, "am Schiff", "in der Messe". Ich würde vermuten, das *-i* in *bei* stamme tatsächlich von *in, im*. Demnach wäre die beiläufige Konnotation der Präposition, so wie die Wendung mit Vorgangsverben nahelegt, das Befinden *im* Vorgang.

Der Unterschied zwischen den Bsp 1 und 2 kann in erster Linie der Gewohnheit zugeschrieben werde. Ich vermute mal, 1 wird eher attributiv verstanden, equivalent zu "Ich finde meinen Sohn *schön*". 2 ist dagegen nominiert, und erfordert daher auch regelmäßig Zusammen- und Großschreibung, "beim Suppe-Essen", was wohl der Präposition geschuldet ist. Da nominalisierter Verben immer neutralen Genus tragen, ist die Präpositiin auch immer *beim*. *bei dem* oder *bei der* dürften in diesem Bild hyperkorrekt sein.

Wie das ursprünglich gewachsen ist, würde hier zu weut führen; Soll heißen: Ich weiß es nicht. Tatsächlich sind die Verben, die Präpositionen enthalten, immer Partizipien, es heißt also in aller Regel nicht *Ich sehe meinen Sohn verlierend* sondern *... verlieren*, wenn ein Presenz-Partizip gemeint ist. Das könnte einiges damit zu tun haben. Das Wort *Essen* ist ohnehin ein Spezialfall.

Die letzte Alternative:

> 3. Ich habe ein Auge auf meinen Döner essenden Sohn

Das klingt sehr formell, eher Schriftsprache; Es ist grammatisch in einigen Ausnahmefällen schwierig und für den Hörer irreführend. Bspw. wäre "meinen einen Döner essenden" eher selten, und "meine Döner essenden Kinder" nicht mal mehr eindeutig. Ich habe doch gar keine Kinder.

Bleibt nur zu bemerken: Wenn das Essen im Fokus steht, würde man auch sagen, "Ich beobachte das Suppeessen meines Sohnes.". "meines Sohnes Suppe essen" wäre zweideutig und arg gestelzt.